# openGL texture mapping

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

Hey,
 I am creating a game using openGL in c++
when I try and map a texture to an object it changes the colour of everything else I have drawn
eg everything goes a transparent red or green..

```
glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    Bitmap image;
    image.loadBMP ("Texture.bmp");

    glGenTextures(1, &m_TextureID);
    glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_TextureID);

    glTexEnvf ( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE , GL_MODULATE);
    glTexParameterf ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);

    glTexParameterf ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    gluBuild2DMipmaps ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, image.width, image.height, GL_RGB,    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.data);
    glEnd();
```

this is my texture code and here is how i am mapping the texture

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D);
//glColor3d(1, 0, 0); 
glTexCoord2f (0.0f,0.0f);
glVertex3f(0, 0, 0); // bottom left
glTexCoord2f (1.0f,0.0f);
glVertex3f(10, 0, 0); // bottom right
glTexCoord2f (1.0f,1.0f);
glVertex3f(10, 0.6, 0);// top right
glTexCoord2f (0.0f,1.0f);
glVertex3f(0, 0.6, 0); // top left
glEnd();
```

etc...

all my non textured objects are drawn like this

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);//BACK
glColor3d(1,0,0);
glVertex3f(10, 0, 0);
glVertex3f(10, 0, -5.6);
glVertex3f(10, 0.6, -5.6);
glVertex3f(10, 0.6, 0);
glEnd();
```

etc...
am i missing something really obvious ?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to disable texture mapping for your other objects if you don't want them to be textured.

```
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You switched these two :

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

glEnable should not be called between glBegin() and glEnd()

Other then that, use glGetError and see which exactly call fails.

Comment: @DK10 So, what was the problem?

Comment: i was missing a glDisable somewhere :)